# QGIS Atlas legend contents

Tags: qgis, layouts

It seems to me that the legend and scalebar in QGIS Atlas cannot change per feature. Is there a way to have a separate, manually tweaked scalebar and legend for each page in my Atlas? How do I do this without using some complicated qgis expression?

**EDIT**

Here is a simple atlas to illustrate what I mean by  "manually tweaking" each page in my atlas:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactely you want to achieve, please provide more details. One possible solution I have in mind could be adding a second map with the features for the legend you want to have represented as well as the scale you want to use for the scalebar. To hide this map, place it under some other element (your main map, e non-transparent text-field, a rectangle or so). Than add a scalebar and legend connected to this second map. However, as told before, I'm not sure what is your goal, so elaborate on that.

Comment: I'm not sure what's unclear to you. I have a multi-feature atlas, but I would like to be able to tweak the legend and scale bar size/location *manually* for each page in my Atlas. The solution you propose seems to require expressions for scalebar and legend placement and contents, which I definitely would like to avoid

Comment: If you could add a screeshot it would probably become more clear what you want to do.

Comment: PLease see edit to original question for a couple of screenshots. Let me know if it helps...

Comment: Easiest would be adding a field in the attribute table that contains the information you want to show. Than define that field as source for the text-field

Comment: I'm not sure of the purpose of tweaking this much. It completely defeat the point of atlas functionality. Why don't you create a layout manually for each feature (using style to display the particular feature from your layer) instead? Middle ground approach = you may filter your atlas for the simple cases (no tweaking, no page numbers), create some custom layouts for your particular cases and then reassemble (outside QGIS or with scripting) all PDFs and add page numbers at the end

Comment: Well I have 60 polylone features that I each need to make a map for. I have a raster layer underneath for which I am varying the legend. The scalebar will almost always interfere with the features no matter where I put it. This is why I want to automate the drawing of each feature, but want to manually tweak the legend, scalebar and text.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Clearer but now not sure I can't help more infortunately.

Comment: Yes, now it's clearer what you intend to do. My idea would be to pre-define a number of cases, let's say 4 cases: legend and text on 1) the bottom left, 2) top left, 3) bottom right, 4) top right. Than go through your atlas and note which case is suitable for each atlas-page/atlas feature. Than in the attribute table add a field for your cases: 1, 2, 3, 4. Than you can position your elements with data-driven override. Sorry, this does not seem to be possible in an easier way than using expressions, not sure why you don't want to use them. If interested, I could help you implementing this.

Comment: Just to make it clear: Atlas is for automatization, but you ask for "manually tweaking" - so bringing both together does not really make sense. Can't you think of a layout without interfering elements? That's what the atlas function is made for. Resize your page to make it bigger an add all additional elements like scalebar, legend, text in a blank space. Have the map in one clearly defined place and the other elements somewhere else. Or accept that scalebar is overapping the map - something you can often see.

Comment: @babel Atlas is for automating cycling through features and getting a separate map for each feature. This functionality is great, and I would like to use it. However this does not mean I want the contents, positioning and size of miscellaneous elements like the legend, scale bar and north arrow to also be automated. I want to be able to move these around manually for each drawing to get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an atlas and add as many pages as you have different settings for the postion/look for your elements as text-boxes, scalebars or legends. Than you can style individually each page, tweak manually as you like it. Normally, you would get now an output for each feature on each page. I have created a polygon layer with 8 feateres, see screenshot:

[image]

Than I created an atlas with 4 layout-pages, that means 4  different settings for position and styling of the additional elements (see next screenshot). When you export, you get in total 32 pages of output: each of the 8 feature for each of the 4 layouts (8*4).

[image]

You can avoid that by filtering some pages when exporting: exclude some of the pages when you export the atlas. For this, I created a field "position" in the polygon's atribute table, containing a number, from 1 to 4. It corresponds to the layout in which this feature should be styled. Have a look to the attribute tabe in the first screenshot above: feature 1 und 5 should be styled in layout no.1; feature 2 and 6 in layout no. 2 and so on. You have to assign this values manually as you know which feature you want to present with which layout.

The last step: in your print composer, right-click on the first page and select page properties. Select the symbol for the expression dialogue besides the text "exclude page from export" and click edit (screenshot above). In the expression dialogue you can than add the following expression (screenshot below):

```
if("position" = 1,0,1)
```

It means: If the value stored in your field "position" is 1, than the expression turns to 0 (=FALSE), otherwise to 1 (=TRUE). Thus: if FALSE, this means do NOT exlude page from export, therefore export it. In all other cases, DO EXCLUDE page from export. 
Repeat this this for the other pages, on page 2 with "position" = 2 and so on.

[image]

If you than export your atlas, you well get 8 pages, ordered like that: feature 1 in layout 1, feature 2 in layout 2, feature 3 in layout 3,feature 4 in layout 4, feature 5 in layout 1, feature 6 in layout 2, feature 7 in layout 3,feature 8 in layout 4. If you want to change a feature to be displayed in another layout, just change the value in the field of your attribute table.

If you want to sort the pages to have all similar looking pages together (thus: first all pages in layout 1, than all in layout 2 and so on), go to the tab Atlas (where you define your atlas configuration) and select sort according to and select your position-field.

I have exported the atlas as pdf - see how it looks: https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/epytbZMo5ouedFm

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the information you want to show in the legend-title or in the separate text-box in the attribute table in a field. Than you can simply add the content of that filed as legend-titel or text of your text-box.

For the text-box in item properties for main properties just insert  `[% "Name" %]` - whereas Name is the name of the field in your attribute table (repleace it to match the name of the field you want to use). Alternatively, you can also click on "insert expression" below and than go to "fields and values" (in the column in the middle) to select the field whose content you want to appear (no complicated expression at all).

For the legend title go to the item properties of the legend. In the title-field select the symbol on the right and than edit. In the expression editor do the same as described above: open "fields and values" and select the field that contains the information for your legend-title.

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned to you I cannot use expressions. The modifications are not consistent for each page in the Atlas. These have to be manual modifications

Comment: So than you shold be more clear what kind of modifications appear and what are the criteria for the modifications you want to implement. Maybe an atlas is not the right instrument to use than. Consider creating a multi-page layout. But if just the legend/textbox-elements should appear in different parts of the atlas-page, than this can also be done be information stored in the attribute table. You don't have to bother with expressions, just insert them, it's easy.

Comment: The modifications are simple: positioning, text contents and size of the legend, north arrow and scalebar. These are on a feature by feature basis. Can you store this type of information in the attribute table?